# Laravel Application Configuration issues

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have an laravel(4.2) application, I have tried to configure in my local system i'm getting following errors.

Images:

[Not found http exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgxuP.png)

[fatel error application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAGjJ.png)

what should I miss while configuring the application.

Here is my Routes folder in /app/routes.php

---

```html
<?php
Route::group(array("prefix" => "api"), function()
{
  Route::resource('user', 'UserController'); 
  Route::get('user/verify/{confirmation_code}', 'UserController@verify');
  Route::post('user/login', 'UserController@login');
  Route::post('user/guest', 'UserController@guest');
  Route::post('user/update', 'UserController@updateUserProfile');
  Route::post('user/change_password', 'PasswordController@change');
  Route::get('user/reset_password/{code}', 'PasswordController@reset');
  Route::post('user/forgot_password', 'PasswordController@forgot');
  Route::resource('feedback', 'FeedbackController');
  Route::group(array("before" => "auth.basic"), function () {
    Route::get('user/cio/favpoint/{id}', 'FavPointsController@showCIO');
    Route::post('user/cio/favpoint', 'FavPointsController@CIOFavPoint');
    Route::get('user/cio/favpoint', 'FavPointsController@getCIOFavPoint');
    Route::post('user/cio/favpoint/edit', 'FavPointsController@editCIOFavPoint');
    Route::get('user/citizen/favpoint/{id}', 'FavPointsController@showCitizen');
    Route::post('user/citizen/favpoint', 'FavPointsController@citizenFavPoint');
    Route::get('user/citizen/favpoint', 'FavPointsController@getCitizenFavPoint');
    Route::post('user/citizen/favpoint/edit', 'FavPointsController@editCitizenFavPoint');
    Route::get('url', 'UrlController@index');
  });
});
?>
```

Comment: Did you try 'composer install'?

Comment: I tried with the composer, I removed vendor folder and used composer to install, no result..

Comment: The first error means that laravel was told to go to a route which was not defined. So for that one needs to go through the routes.php.

As far as the second error is concerned it means that Laravel was expecting to find a Class in a ServiceProvider which it could not find.
Let us address your problem(s) one by one. 

Can you share your routes.php?

Comment: Could you show your route file and how you request in your url

Comment: @tramp & Sultan: i updated the post with the routes.php script

Comment: All your routes are grouped under `api` namespace. The URL you're attempting to access does not match any of them hence the `NotFoundHttpException` is thrown.

Comment: As for the 2nd error, post the code from that service provider as well as it's usage in the `config/app.php` file. It's quite possible there is some typo that causes this.

Comment: Right. I do not see the route mentioned in the image over here. Since you are using your local machine; I am sure you would have run php artisan serve... which folder are you in while you are trying to execute it ??

Answer (score 0):

The 'NotFoundHttpException' means Laravel wasn't able to find a route to for the request.

I hope you using it from windows machine. And have you set up virtual host to run laravel?

I think this  problem for virtual host. Please check it